# Print list of parts from various sets in compact format

Tags: sets

So I've bought a few big box sets over the ages **rambling starts** *(like just recently, a few 11016 because I could get them cheap, a couple of 11019 (I have an older Mindstorms kit which may or may not still work), 11013 because they're pretty, a 11022 because it was cheap at Costco)* **rambling ends** with the intention of doing stuff and now I'm trying to get around to doing stuff.

This involves sorting and storing them, and that's a bit hard when I'm not as skilled as I pretend to be to people who just see big piles of bricks. It'd be great to have a printout of all the different parts with what categories they belong to and such to help sort them together properly.

What I'd like is to be able to print a list of all the parts I have in something like [a set inventory on Brickset](https://brickset.com/inventories/11016-1) (really only need the image > element name columns, although don't care how many in each set column). Several thoughts I've had already:

- Sure, I could print the inventory from Brickset for all the different sets, but there'd be a lot of duplicates, and when it can be 20 pages for a set, that's a lot of ink to go through. I could probably mess with the CSS before printing to cut that down a bit, but it doesn't solve the problem with all the duplicates. *(Sure, I don't like using too much paper either, but paper isn't run by a cartel  like ink is.)*
- I can get a CSV list of each set from Brickset, and I can probably merge the files and delete rows with the same part ID, but then it's not exactly a pretty format. *(Cue inner geek saying "but Python can do anything!)*
- Googled this and one of the top results was to create a brick list of Rebrickable and export it as a HTML table. Done that, I mean technically it works, but I'd once again have to mess with the CSS to try and get it to be a lot less free space, and doesn't contain all the info I'd want (like category).
- Brickstock is designed for sellers by the looks of it, and has its own print function, but that looks like it's designed for individual orders or something, doesn't contain things like category, and again isn't all that dense (looks prettier yes, takes up way too much paper, yes) and unlike a web service and CSS if I want to create my own look... I could probably figure out Qt Script (looks pretty similar to a lot of C-style scripting languages), but it'd be a lot of effort.

Is there something blatantly obvious I'm missing? Is my mission doomed from the start? Do I just settle for continuing to look at a screen?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you really need to print this? BrickStock is what I use when I inventory sets. You can change quantities and track what you have this way. Plus it does tell you the category of the element, and you can sort the list by this column,

Comment: @PhilB. Thanks for the reply. I'm not really that interested in how many of each piece I have (plus I can't find data for all the sets I've ever bought... but I think that's a matter for another topic) since I'm not planning on selling them or anything, just building stuff myself. I just want to go through my boxes of bricks, pull something out, and be able to flip a page or few until I see a picture that looks like it, then put it in a smaller, more specialised box. Seems like it would be a lot of hassle if I had to keep a device around to scroll around until I find the right picture.